# Azure - Copy file to FTP every 10 minutes

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

For a REST API hosted on an Azure App Service, how can I do the following every 10 minutes?

- Hit a certain API route that updates a txt file that lives on the App Service
- Copy the updated txt file onto an FTP server

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [Azure WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create) to do that. Azure WebJobs is a functionality of Azure app service, you can use it directly if you are using Azure App Service.

Azure WebJobs supports [CRON task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#CreateScheduledCRON) natively which meets your requirement perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked into WebJobs and they seem to do exactly what I need. I think I can use a Triggered WebJob and set the trigger to every 10 minutes. Do you have any advice regarding how to create the job script that actually uploads a file to a separate FTP?

Comment: Hi @Ben I am glad to, please mark my solution as an answer and open another question. On stack overflow,its one question one case, thanks!